# XML File Errors - no ressource found

Tags: android, xml, r.java-file

Here's my problem.

I'm currently setting up a relative Layout for a TicTacToe-Game.
It consists of 9 ImageButtons, and 8 Views which I use to get the grid.

Either I have errors in my xmlfile, saying "no ressource found"(even if id's are correctly build into my r.class) or the errors disappear when I retype my layout referrences to other view. But if I retype it, clean project and build it again, eclipse lets my R.class disappear.

Here my XML-File:

```
    `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/notepad2" >    

    <View 
    android:layout_width="5dp" 
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/hor2"
    android:id="@+id/vert1"
    />

 <View 
    android:layout_width="5dp" 
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/hor3"
    android:id="@+id/vert2"
    />

 <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld4"
    android:layout_above="@id/feld4"
    android:id="@+id/hor1"
    />

 <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld5"
    android:layout_above="@id/feld5"
    android:id="@+id/hor2"
    />



 <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld6"
    android:layout_above="@id/feld6"
    android:id="@+id/hor3"
    />

  <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld4"
    android:layout_below="@id/feld4"
    android:id="@+id/hor4"
    />

 <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld5"
    android:layout_below="@id/feld5"
    android:id="@+id/hor5"
    />

 <View 
    android:layout_width="50dp" 
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"

    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/feld5"
    android:layout_below="@id/feld6"
    android:id="@+id/hor6"
    />




<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vert1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/vert1"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_above="@id/hor2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/hor2"
     />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld3"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vert2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/vert2"
    />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vert1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/feld5"
    />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld5"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld6"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vert2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/feld5"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld7"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vert1"
    android:layout_below="@id/hor4"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld8"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vert1"
    android:layout_below="@id/hor4"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/feld9"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/leer"
    android:contentDescription="@string/feld"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vert2"
    android:layout_below="@id/hor4"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/winners"
    android:text="@string/winner"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/anotherGame"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_above="@id/winners"
    android:text="@string/newGameButton"
/>
```

`

Anyone an idea how to fix?

I already tried the usual. Corrected the 'mistakes' in the xml file, cleaned project, built it again and so on. Nothing worked.

Comment: what are exactly the errors? can you post the console build information?

Comment: Which resources cannot be found? One or two or none of them?

Comment: '[2012-11-27 18:28:11 - TicTacToe] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-11-27 18:29:27 - TicTacToe] Error in an XML file: aborting build.' while r class is available. The Errors are all "Couldn't resolve ressource" though id is already in r class.

Comment: Couldn't resolve resource @id/hor2
Couldn't resolve resource @id/feld2
Couldn't resolve resource @id/vert1
Couldn't resolve resource @id/feld4
Couldn't resolve resource @id/feld5
Couldn't resolve resource @id/vert2
Couldn't resolve resource @id/feld6
Couldn't resolve resource @id/hor4
Couldn't resolve resource @id/winners are the errors while having an r class. That's okay, because they are apparently not writen in the r class. So I try clean Project and Build project, because that's how I usually fix it if a ressource is missing in R. But instead of adding this ressources R vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Sam is on the right track, it is actually bad practice to user `@+id/` when you are not setting the `android:id` attribute.  `@+id/` actually tries to add that id to your R file if it does not already exist.  This can cause problems where you remove the element that another one aligns based on but an error will not be thrown since you are using `@+id/`

Instead, you should define the layouts above views that align based on them in your xml file.  For Example, `winners` should go below `anotherGame`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/anotherGame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/winners"
    android:text="@string/newGameButton"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/winners"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/winner"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

If you absolutely cannot get around having all views declared above the views that align based on them, you can fall back on using `@+id/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already fixed it now.

It was just the order of elements in the XML-File.

If you align a View A relative to another View B then the View B must have been given an Id above the declaration of View A.

Comment: @PaulLich How does this answer your question? The example produces the _exact_ error in your question: you are referencing winners with `@id/winners` before it has been declared with `@+id/winners`...

Comment: @JamesMcCracken Wherever `@+id/` code references an id that doesn't exist, you will receive a warning... And the suggestion of ordering the Views falls under your own "bad practice" explanation: If View C depends on B depends on A is ordered the way you describe, removing View B will still require you to update View C...

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems like this one, from your first View:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="5dp" 
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/hor2"
    android:id="@+id/vert1"
    />
```

`hor2` has not been declared yet, you must use `@+id`:

```
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hor2"
```

You need to update all of these to use the proper notation.

Comment: And when you define `hor2` you can define it like: `android:id="@id/hor2`, without the `+`.